# Match two images of different intensity, size, and taken from different sources and computing difference between them

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

- Problem statement:

Given an input image, find and extract the image similar to that from the cluttered scene. Now from the extracted Image find the differences in the extracted image from the input image.

- My Approach:

Uptill now I have used SIFT features for feature matching and affine transform to extract the image from the cluttered scene.

But I am not able to find a method good enough and feasible for me to find the difference in the input image and extracted image.

[image: Input Image]

[image: This is the extracted image.]

[image: Used Feature based methods to find and extract image from cluttered scene]

Comment: what do you mean by difference between two images ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there exists a particular technique for your problem. If the traditional methods does not suite your need, maybe you can use the keypoints (SIFT) again to estimate the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You have already done most work by matching image using SIFT.
Next you can use corresponding SIFT matched points to estimate the warp-affine factor. Apply required warp affine to second image and crop such that the images are super-imposable.

Now you can calculate absolute difference of the two image and SAD or SSD as a difference indication.